# Can I directly interact with audio endpoints on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, audio

I am trying to write a pro music/audio processing application, and I would like to be able to interact with the audio inputs/outputs at a very low level - ideally something allowing me to apply effects to the audio inputs and output this in real-time, similar to programs like Logic, Ableton etc.

I have written a pretty basic program that detects audio endpoint devices and can change their volumes using the MMDevice interface, but this is nowhere near the functionality I would like.

I have learned from the Microsoft docs that the four core-audio APIs are:

- MMDevice
- WASAPI
- DeviceTopology
- EndpointVolume

but it doesn't seem like any of these have the capabilities that I need. I'm thinking that I will need to be able to interact with the speakers at the level of setting the position of the membrane at a given time.

Is this even possible? If so, what can I use to do this?

Comment: Maybe XAudio2 does what you want.

Comment: Modern operating systems wall practically everyone off from direct access to the underlying hardware. Part of this is self-defense, many nasty things can be accomplished when you can acquire that level of system control, and a large part is abstracting away the differences in the hardware. If you need to do something that can't fit into the abstraction you may have to delve into the dark secrets of Windows Drivers.

Comment: Usually pro audio software use Steinberg's ASIO technology. You can download the ASIO SDK on [Steinberg's 3rd Party Developer](https://www.steinberg.net/en/company/developers.html) website. It is free of charge but comes with a license agreement which you have to sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Windows Audio Session API (WASAPI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CoreAudio/wasapi) is the best bet for this purpose. It allows interaction with audio endpoints and setting up audio streams (which are streams of data that you can send or receive in real time). A good example is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CoreAudio/rendering-a-stream).